# Is there any edges that function similarly to "tagged", but includes non-public posts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tagging

I have a question about Facebook Graph API since this is my first time using it. Is there any edges that can be used to get all posts that tag a particular page?  I tried using [tagged](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tagged/), and while the result appears as intended, posts that aren't public (friends, friends except, and private) aren't included.

Comment: Unless your app has permission from the specific person that made the non-public post - of course not.

Comment: @04FS Ah, I'm not necessarily developing an application that runs on Facebook. I'm attempting to create a console application that retrieves all posts that tag my client's company page using Graph API, which is why non-public posts should be included in the result.. I suppose there's no other way around this problem since in this case I'm not developing an actual Facebook app?

Comment: If you are using the Graph API, then you are using an app. That has nothing whatsoever to do with “runs (directly) on Facebook.”

Comment: @04FS I'm not sure whether to ask this or not since it's becoming rather off-topic, but how to ask for other user's permission when they're about to create a post that tags/mentions the page? From what I understand, the poster and the page isn't really "connected" to each other as far as permission goes...

Comment: There is no way to do that specifically. (How would it be, you can not _react_ to an occurrence, that you currently have no “clearance” to be notified about in the first place.) Just accept that non-public posts are simply non of your business - doesn’t matter if they tagged your page or not.

Comment: @04FS I see. Thanks for the answer! That really cleared a lot of confusion :)